# How is user registration form created in Plone?

Tags: plone

I am using Plone 5. I'm wondering how the user login and registration can be put on the webpage.
Where is the data saved and how can it be retrieved for further use in Rapido?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a basic Plone site, those data are saved internally (in `portal_memberdata`), but they might be saved in another place (depending on the plugins you might have declared in `acl_users`, typically it could be in a LDAP directory or ActiveDirectory).

Nevertheless, the location they are saved to makes no difference regarding the way you can retrieve them from Rapido.
To get a user object, use the Plone API (so through `context.api` in Rapido):

```
current_user = context.api.user.get_current()
another_user = context.api.user.get(username='bob')
```

And to access user's information, use the `getProperty` method:

```
current_user.getProperty('email')
another_user.getProperty('fullname')
```

Note: the existing properties are the ones listed in Site setup / Users and groups / Member fields (http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@member-fields). That's also the place where you can create new user attributes if you need.

Comment: Thanks! What I wanted is when someone enters the website, there will an option register/login. How is it enabled so it's there on the top of the webpage?

Comment: That's a Plone parameter: go to Site setup / Security and then ckeck "Enable self-registration".

Comment: For the survey I am doing, is it possible to get the data for each user as in which user chose which concepts?